# Choice of method for Stochastic Differential Equation Solution

Tags: stochastic-ode

I have to simulate the following differential equation:

$$\dot{x}=p$$

$$\dot{p}=-x-x^3-\gamma p+F\cos\omega t+ \delta F(t)$$

where

$$\langle F(t)F(t')\rangle=2\gamma k_BT\delta(t-t')$$

$$\langle F(t)\rangle=0$$

$F=0.006$, $\omega=1.016$, $k_BT=0.008$, $\gamma=0.001$

I want to simulate for a long time of $T=800$ and want a decently accurate solution. There are many methods to choose from like Euler-Maruyama, Milstein, Runge-Kutta, etc. I was wondering which method to choose.

What are the qualifying criteria between all these methods?

When is the improved accuracy useless due to the presence of a stochastic term?

Comment: What kind of accuracy do you care about? Do you need correct trajectories or just correct average quantities?

Comment: correct trajectories preferably

Comment: the idea is to track the variation in phase plot (x,p) by computing trajectories

Comment: If you remove the cubic term, you can solve Langevin equation analytically. So in this limit you can verify the accuracy of several integration methods as regards to calculations of <y^2(t)>, dispersion, and correlation <y(t)y(t')>. That should be a necessary, but not sufficient, condition for a good integration method. Another check you could make is turn off the coherent drive (set F=0) and see if you obtain the stationary probability distribution and the equipartition $<p^2/2m>=kT/2$. There is a large body of research on stochastic resonance that could check also for possible solvers too.

Comment: @minmax thanks i'll do the above to see how the methods fare against each other.

Comment: Is there a way to confirm accuracy in paths for different methods for SDEs, with time. It seems this accuracy must vary from system to system, depending crucially on the equations